# Decimal Value is Zero when it should be 0.0x

Tags: c#, decimal, division

If this was previously talked about, I'm sorry, I had a hard time searching on this.

I am calculating a depreciation rate. One portion of our calculation is 1/life in months. My table stores this data in a `decimal` field. I tried `test = 1 / estimatedLife;` but the result of the calculation of `test` (which is defined as a `decimal`) is 0.

Say the estimated life is 36 months. So 1/36 should equal 0.02777778.

Any thoughts of what I am doing wrong?

BTW, I changed the `test` to a double and had the same result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try:

```
test = 1.0M / estimatedLife;
```

Comment: What does the "M" do? I did do 1.00 and that worked great! I got a compile error on 1.0M

Comment: The `M` makes it a `decimal`.  `1.00` is a `double`, which is less precise.

Comment: As SLaks said, it makes it a decimal. Here is the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75(VS.71).aspx

Comment: It must have been due to me forgetting to change test back to decimal from double. It works now.

Answer (score 5):

Another built-in alternative is [Decimal.Divide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.divide.aspx):

```
test = Decimal.Divide(1, estimatedLife);
```

More to write, but pretty explicit I'd say.

Answer (score 2):

Your code divides two integers, then assigns the result (which is also an integer) to a `decimal` variable.

You need to switch to `decimal` division by making at least one of the operands a `decimal`, like this: `1.0M / estimatedLife`.

Answer (score 2):

estimatedLife is an int, isn't it. Try this:

```
    decimal test = 1 / (decimal) estimatedLife;
```

or use SwDevMan81's suggestion:

```
    test = 1.0M / estimatedLife;
```

The issue is that integer division throws away everything after the decimal point. One of the arguments has to be a decimal for you to get the result you want.

The [documentation link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75(VS.71).aspx) that he posted in a comment says:

> If you want a numeric real literal to be treated as decimal, use the suffix m or M

so 1.0M means "a literal of type decimal with the value 1.0"

Answer (score 2):

just to add, if you require a specific precision (I noticed your output was set to 8 decimal places) you can use

```
decimal test = Math.Round(1M / estimatedLife,8);
```