# Double variables give unexpected result

Tags: c#, variables

I am not sure about what is going on with these two variables. "milliV" is a double, "param1a" is a double, being param1a= 65, I should get out 1.588. The result I get instead is **= 0**. How is that possible?

```
  double milliV=0.0;
  milliV= (5/1023*param1a/200*1000);
```

[image]

Comment: What type is `param1a`?

Comment: might want to try `5.0/1023.0` and `200.0*1000.0`, just so you're sure you're not mixing some integer results in there.

Comment: As I said, is a double.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Decimal Value is Zero when it should be 0.0x](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2449990/decimal-value-is-zero-when-it-should-be-0-0x)

Comment: I got it. What a stupid mistake I did. You are all correct. As soon as I add decimals to 5 (5.00) the operation is correct. I think the compiler should assume by default that without decimal, the decimal is 0 being the operators doubles. Why not?

Comment: You typed 5, so you meant 5, not 5.0. It's good it doesn't guess.

Comment: @doctorlove: The compiler could give a warning that *an expression that contains a variable has a constant result*. (I can no longer add this warning to the C# compiler but I will check to see if Coverity's C# checkers will catch this one.)

Comment: @EricLippert, thanks. That would be nice for those days....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because `5/1023` that's an integer division so the result is integer too. Try with this

```
milliV= (5.0/1023*param1a/200.0*1000);
```

As long as one of the elements of the operation is `double`, the result will be `double` too

Comment: @Ms. Nobody: it happen to all of us, specially when Jon Skeet is who  answers ;)

Answer (score 5):

5/1023 is problem 5 and 1023 are integers so 5/1023 = 0

Answer (score 4):

it looks that 5/1023 = 0 since both 5 and 1023 are integers

try change 5/1023*param1a/200*1000 into

```
5.0 / 1023.0 * param1a / 200.0 * 1000.0
```